# Find duplicates based on non-duplicates column

Tags: sql

Based on below table

```
id  name  cardId
--------
1   John    123
2   Mark    123
3   Tom     231
4   Debra   321
5   Debra   321
6   Debra   321
7   Tom     321
```

How can I select records with same cardId but with different names?
Output should looks like this

```
  name  cardId
--------
   John    123
   Mark    123
   Debra   321
   Tom     321
```

EDIT:
Just to be clear. One user can have multiple cardId, but one cardId cannot be shared between different users. How can I find this?

Comment: So, `3 Tom (231)` should not be included since it's not a duplicate?

Comment: @smoksnes that's right

Answer (score 2):

```
with t as (
    select 1 Id ,  'John' name, 123 CardId union all
    select 2 ,  'Mark' , 123    union all
    select 3 ,  'Tom' , 231 union all
    select 4 ,  'Debra' , 321   union all
    select 5 ,  'Debra' , 321   union all
    select 6 ,  'Debra' , 321   union all
    select 7 ,  'Tom' , 321 union all
    select 8 ,  'Tom' , 322
)
```

I think the test data needs another row for Tom, with the `max()/group by` solution Tom 322 is returned but according to the specification should not be as it's a single CardId

```
  select distinct name, CardId from (
        select name, CardId, Count(*) over(partition by CardId) c
        from t
    )x
    where c>1
```

You need to count the number of distinct CardIds and filter single rows

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists`:

```
select distinct t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.cardid = t.cardid and t2.name <> t.name
             );
```

With an index on `(cardid, name)`, this is probably the fastest way to approach the query.

Comment: That should work, I think you have the equality/inequality the wrong way round?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple group by would do the trick:

```
SELECT
    name,
    MAX(cardId)
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

**Edit**
Since the question has been updated, I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
    MIN(name),
    MAX(name),
    cardId,
    COUNT(name) name_count
FROM table
GROUP BY cardId
HAVING COUNT(name) >= 2
```

You could also do this by joining the table to itself, but the advantage of the version with `HAVING` is that it doesn't give duplicate results when you have 3 or more people with the same `cardId`.

Comment: I'm getting one name and one max cardId. that's not what i want

Comment: Have you used group by name as Wolph suggested?

Comment: I just tried it, and it gives exactly the result that is mentioned.

Comment: I don't think the max() will work. If you had another Tom CardId 322 it would be returned, but should not be since it's the only one, if I understand correctly?

Comment: @sTTu I'm only now reading the updated question. That's indeed a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

USING `GROUP BY` will solve you problem

```
select name, max(cardid) as cardid from table_1
group by name 
order by cardid asc
```